# HERE Optimized Routing with turn-by-turn directions

Tags: here-api

What service should I use for Optimized Routing with turn-by-turn directions - I tried Large Scale matrix but that is not it.

I need to define a starting point and then up to 500 locations and have the route optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the fleet telematics waypoint sequencing API documentation as follows : 
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/dev_guide/topics/quick-start-simple-car.html
Note : The maximum number of waypoints including the start point and end point is 120 without traffic and 50 with traffic. If the routing mode pedestrian is used, the distance between each two of the waypoints must not be greater than 5km.
Please let us know if does this align with the use case or you need to specify all 500 locations in one go and splitting waypoints won't be possible in your scenario.What limitations have you encountered with large scale matrix api.